# 500 internal error with authentication password in express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, postman

as a starting [copypasteprogrammer](https://hackernoon.com/your-node-js-authentication-tutorial-is-wrong-f1a3bf831a46) I started to add some [salting and hashing](http://devsmash.com/blog/password-authentication-with-mongoose-and-bcrypt) to my app. The creation of a new User works fine. But the authentication of a user/password in Postman gives me a hard time. I keep getting errors. Now a 500 internal service error. Who can give me a little advice?

Here the schema:

```js
const userSchema = new Schema({
    
    userName: { //email
        type: String,
        required: true, 
        unique: true,
        trim: true
    },
       password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
  
});


// hashing and salting before saving
userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    let user = this;
    // only hash the password if it has been modified (or is new)
    if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();

    //generate a salt
    bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function (err, salt) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        // hash the password using our new salt
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function (err, hash) {
            if (err) return next(err);

            // override the cleartext password with the hashed one
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
});
    


mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Here the routes:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const ctrlAuthFiles = require('../controllers/authFiles');

router
    .route('/login')
    .post(ctrlAuthFiles.userLogin);

module.exports = router;
```

Here the controller:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const User1 = mongoose.model('User');

//fetch user and test password verification
const userLogin = function (req, res) {
    if (req.body) {
        User1
            .findOne({ userName: req.body.username })
            .exec((err, user) => {
                if (!user) {
                    res
                        .status(404)
                        .json({
                            "message": "username or password not found"
                        });
                    return;
                } else if (err) {
                    res
                        .status(404)
                        .json(err);
                    return;
                }
            });

        User1.comparePassword(req.body.password, function (err, isMatch) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(isMatch);
        });

        User1.methods.comparePassword = function (candidatePassword, cb) {
            bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function (err, isMatch) {
                if (err)
                    return cb(err);
                cb(null, isMatch);
            });
        }


    } else {
        res
            .status(404)
            .json({
                "message": "no username or password"
            });
    }
        
};
```

Comment: can you update your error log?

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: you said you are getting `500 internal service error`. for which line, and what error says?

Comment: not specific a line, it 's Postman who gives me this error

Comment: No, postman does not give you the 500 error, it just reports the 500 error it gets from your express server. So you have to check in the log of your server, or the console output of the terminal where your server is running, what the actual error is

Comment: The app isn 't crashing. The node.js command prompt rapports a 'POST /user/login 500 21.606 ms - 4196'. Sorry I wish I could be more helpful then this.